# In Spark SQL, transform JSON key name into value

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

It seems like there should be a function for this in Spark SQL similar to pivoting, but I haven't found any solution to transforming a JSON key into a a value. Suppose I have a badly formed JSON (the format of which I cannot change):

```
{"A long string containing serverA": {"x": 1, "y": 2}}
```

how can I process it to

```
{"server": "A", "x": 1, "y": 2}
```

?

I read the JSONs into an an `sql.dataframe` and would then like to process them as described above:

```
val cs = spark.read.json("sample.json")
  .???
```

Comment: A direct transformation of the key name into a key-value pair, as shown in the example, would be the neatest way, but I would also accept something like "newkey": "A long string containing serverA"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to use only spark functions and no UDFs, you could use `from_json` to parse the json into a map (we need to specify a schema). Then you just need to extract the information with spark functions.
One way to do it is as follows:

```scala
val schema = MapType(
    StringType,
    StructType(Array(
        StructField("x", IntegerType),
        StructField("y", IntegerType)
    ))
)

spark.read.text("...")
    .withColumn("json", from_json('value, schema))
    .withColumn("key", map_keys('json).getItem(0))
    .withColumn("value", map_values('json).getItem(0))
    .withColumn("server",
        // Extracting the server name with a regex
        regexp_replace(regexp_extract('key, "server[^ ]*", 0), "server", ""))
    .select("server", "value.*")
    .show(false)
```

which yields:

```
+------+---+---+
|server|x  |y  |
+------+---+---+
|A     |1  |2  |
+------+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks, Oli! This would work perfectly with my toy dataset. In my real dataset I have many more key-value mappings in the inner JSON, and I wonder if I can do the transformation without having to specify a schema.

Comment: With `from_json` you need to specify the schema but there are other ways to go at it. What's your json like exactly?

Comment: It is from a client and I am not sure if I can post the entire structure. It goes like```{
  "Statistics for client XXX": {
    "ipaddress": "XX.XXX.XXX.XXX",
    "totalAccessRequests": 243,
    "totalDupAccessRequests": 0,
    "totalAccessAccepts": 51,```
and so on, with 17 numeric values. I can of course write a schema like you did here, but at that point I wonder if I go a completely different route (parsing into a case class in scala)

Comment: In any case I will accept your answer since it works perfectly for the toy dataset I had originally posted.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not solve your problem :)

Comment: There are several ways to solve your problem. The 1st one would be to simply use a scala library to parse the json within a UDF. Another solution could be to read the text file, fix the json, write it back on the disk and then read it with `spark.read.json`.

Comment: I am using a sample JSON from disk for testing the parsing, but this will later be a continuous data stream, so I won't have the option to fix the JSON by writing it to disk. In spite of the elegant solution you gave here for the simple case with two values in the inner JSON, I think I will go the full-fledge case class route.

Comment: It works fine by defining a case class for the inner JSON, then
```
private val innerSchema = Encoders.product[MyCaseClass].schema
  private val schema = MapType(
    StringType,
    clientStatsSchema
  )
```

Comment: Nice ;) Glad you found a solution!